# How to avoid Antivirus Firewall blocking?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, anti-virus

I just released a game that requires a PC and a mobile phone to communicate via UDP in a local area network. I have a mechanism that adds rules to the Windows firewall for the game.

However, some Antivirus software has blocked the game with its firewall, making it unplayable.
How do I avoid this scenario? Should I contact some of the Antivirus providers? Or, sign our program with a more potent certificate? Or, should I use some of the well-known ports for the game instead?

Comment: Can I know the reason my question was downvoted please?

Answer (score 0):

Just use well-known ports. Creating custom ports is usually a terrible idea.

Otherwise, you will need to get the users to add their own exceptions. Most enterprise software offers this advice.

Comment: I went with the port that Windows automatically provide. I'll try the well-known port first. Then, I'll let you know.

Comment: Disagree with well-known port for a custom protocol. Protocols should not pretend to be something else that already has a pass. If it is an existing protocol like http, sure use the traditional port.

Comment: @JohnMahowald What would you suggest?